# Building blockchain on macOS Sierra (10.12)

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I am trying to build a bitcoind client or similar program on my macbook so that I can access the blockchain information for analytics purposes. Honestly, I dont have the slightest clue how-to do this though. Can someone please explain? Or better yet, is their a simpler way to view the up-to-date blockchain information that I am unaware of?

Comment: have you try using blockchain.info ?

Comment: Well, I want to extract the actual transactions themselves- the entire blockchain

Comment: Is it possible to download the information from blockchain.info daily in the form of csv using python?